# patchy transparent textures

Tags: texturing, transparency

[image]

for some reason some downloaded files come out looking like this. i've noticed it with some, but not all, mixamo fbx files. does this look familiar? any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to adjust your materials

I'm taking a stab here but I'm guessing that you've downloaded these models in the formats you've stated, and are using Eevee?

If so, then I'm fairly confident in my answer.

Go into the materials for your objects scroll down to Settings and check your Blend Mode. Experiment to see which one works best out of the three highlighted in my screenshot here:

[image]

I'm just speaking from experience. If any of my assumptions are wrong, let me know and I'll remove or amend my answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Your assumptions are spot on. Thank you! This has solved a long-standing headache